# MySQL select distinct and determine if only one user_id exists

Tags: mysql, distinct

I would like to run a query to show if there is one or more than one user_id for given poll_id.

Example 1: poll_id 1106 has only user_id 1 for all it's rows.

Example 2: poll_id 1106 has more than one user_id 1 for all it's rows.

[image: two examples images]

Using the example given below, this php code works:

```
$sql = "
SELECT 1 
FROM xf_poll_vote
WHERE poll_id='1106'
having count(distinct user_id) > 1";

// execute SQL query and get result 
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection); 

// format results by row 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) { 

    $user_id[] = $row["user_id"];

}

$count = count($user_id);

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 1
from yourTable
where poll_id = @yourPoll_id
having count(distinct user_id) > 1
```

if returns you anything, that poll_id have more than one user. If not, only have one or zero users

Comment: Thank you, Gonzalo, that works perfect. I'll update my original question with the php code I used. When I echo user_id and I get a 0 that means all user_id's are the same. If I get a 1 that means there are more than one user_id's.

Answer (score 3):

Just a COUNT / DISTINCT I think.

```
SELECT poll_id, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1 THEN 'Many' ELSE 'One' END AS ManyOrOne
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY poll_id
```

Comment: Hello, Kickstart. I tried your example, but my result was the same weather I had one or more user_id's for the same poll_id.

Comment: I double checked it and it should work. Let me knock up a test table like yours and try again.

Comment: Tried it with your sample data and it appears to work as I intended. Gives 1105 poll id along with "one" and 1106 poll id along with "many". Simple to add a where clause if you only want to check a specific poll id.